# Python file metadata

Tags: python, file, properties, metadata

I posted this earlier but it got put on hold as too vague.  Hopefully this clears it up.

I'm looking to populate a table (size x*y, for x items and y properties) from the file metadata in a folder. Specifically I'm looking at music files, so the properties are: year, length, and genre.

I tried looking at questions related to file properties, but those just came back with file size, date last modified, etc.

It's just a for loop:

```
f = open("output.txt", "w")  
for files in folder:  
    year[] += file.year  
    genre[] += file.genre  
    length[] += file.length
    f.write(file.year + "\t" + file.genre + "\t" + file.length + "\n")
```

I just don't know what the python functions are for accessing the metadata, to replace 'file.year' and etc.

EDIT:
I haven't been able to install anything via 'pip' on my computer - is there a trick to it or something?  I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need libraries that parse audio files and extract metadata like [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/), [Mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and such.